# Как сделать Deploy JS-приложения?

Tags: javascript, git

Впервые получил задание сделать Deploy js-приложения.
Есть каталог с файлами. Как и с помощью чего все файлы это собрать воедино (сделать deploy)?

Файлы git нужно исключить из каталога. Какие это файлы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странная формулировка твоего задания... Как я понял, речь идет о сборке проекта (production build) через webpack. Выложи плиз содержимое файла package.json и webpack.config, без них ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

всё решилось с помощью трёх команд: npm install, npm run dev, npm deploy